# Infinite product convergence in complex analysis: $\prod (1+a_k)$ and $\prod|(1+ a_k)|$

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, absolute-convergence

If $\prod (1+a_k)$ converges, then to prove that $\prod|(1+ a_k)|$ converges.
Any suggestion and idea about this will be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $x \mapsto |x|$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Look at the fact that the only thing that replacing $(1+a_k)$ with $|(1+a_k)|$ can change is the sign (but not the [absolute] value) of the whole product.